# The R mstate package takes data that has a "status" variable. The "status" can either be 0 or 1. What does 0 mean and what does 1 mean?

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov-models

[image: Example data]

This is some example data. Below is a quote from the paper (Wreede et al 2010) regarding the "status" variable:

"We need one line for
each individual for each transition for which he/she is at risk,
containing data about her/his identity (id), the current transition
(from, to, trans), the time of entry in the current state
(Tstart), the time when he/she stops being at risk for the
transition (Tstop), either due to an event or to censoring, as
indicated by status."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general:**

In the setting of time-to-event analysis which a Kaplan-Meier survival analysis in essence is you need core variables. One of this needed variables is an event variable. In your example depicted with `status`:

`status == 0` means no event occured.
`status == 1` means event occured.

event in this setting can be everything like: death, accident, success, .... -> then status 0 says no death and status 1 says death.

**In the original documentation:**
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mstate/mstate.pdf

status is either:

1. a vector describing status at end of follow-up, having the same length as Tstop,

or

2. a character string indicating the column name that contains this
   information.